# Canon Shutter Count Checker Software for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, software-center, canon

Need Shutter Count Checker **Software** for my **Canon EOS DSLR** camera. 
 And can you describe, "how to install it in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"?

Answer (score 4):

1. Install gPhoto2 in terminal

   - `sudo apt-get install gphoto2`
2. Connect the USB Camera to the Computer
3. Turn on the Camera
4. Run `gphoto2` to read the shuttercount

   - `gphoto2 --get-config /main/status/shuttercounter`